# Why is std::optional's assignment operator not usable in compile-time context in this simple example?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, constexpr, stdoptional

After fiddling with the Compiler Explorer (as well as reading cppref.com on std::optional) for half an hour, I give up. Not much else to say other than I don't understand why this code doesn't compile. Someone please explain this, and maybe show me a workaround if there is one?
All the member functions of `std::optional` I'm using here are `constexpr`, and indeed should be computable at compile time, given that the optional type here - `size_t` - is a primitive scalar type.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    std::optional<size_t> index;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        index = 1;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>)
        index = 0;

    return index;
}
 
static_assert(index_for_type<int>().has_value());
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YKh5qT4aP

Comment: `index = 1;` is an assignment, and IIRC you can't have that in a constant expression.  If you just directly return it works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/Mseh4hjj6

Comment: @NathanOliver, I agree the assignment is useless in this reduced example, but it would be nice for the actual code I needed this for. But more importantly, the assignment is also constexpr (conditionally), why doesn't it work at compile time?

Comment: Isn't this a typo: https://godbolt.org/z/bGrWoo35K ?

Comment: @MarekR, did you only change the type of the optional? It wasn't a typo, I intend to return `std::optional<size_t>` with a fixed type, but it's quite curious that your version works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's simply this a bit:

```cpp
constexpr std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    std::optional<size_t> index;
    index = 1;
    return index;
}

static_assert(index_for_type().has_value());
```

With `index = 1;` the candidate you're trying to invoke amongst the [assignment operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D) is #4:

```cpp
template< class U = T >
optional& operator=( U&& value );
```

Note that this candidate was not originally made `constexpr` in C++20, it was a recent DR ([P2231R1](https://wg21.link/p2231r1%5D)). libstdc++ does not yet implement this change, which is why your example does not compile. As of now, it is perfectly correct C++20 code. The library just hasn't quite caught up yet.

---

The reason that [Marek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68230972/2069064) suggestion works:

```cpp
constexpr std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    std::optional<size_t> index;
    index = size_t{1};
    return index;
}

static_assert(index_for_type().has_value());
```

Is because instead of calling assignment operator `#4` (which would otherwise continue to not work for the same reason, it's just not `constexpr` in this implementation yet), it switches to calling operator `#3` (which is `constexpr`):

```cpp
constexpr optional& operator=( optional&& other ) noexcept(/* see below */);
```

Why this one? Because `#4` has this constraint:

> and at least one of the following is true:
>
> - `T` is not a scalar type;
> - `std::decay_t<U>` is not `T`.

Here, `T` is `size_t` (it's the template parameter of the `optional` specialization) and `U` is the argument type. In the original case, `index = 1`, `U` is `int` which makes the second bullet hold (`int` is, indeed, not `size_t`) and thus this assignment operator is valid. But when we change it to `index = size_t{1}`, now `U` becomes `size_t`, so the second bullet is also false, and we lose this assignment operator as a candidate.

This leaves the copy assignment and move assignment as candidates, of which the latter is better. The move assignment *is* `constexpr` in this implementation, so it works.

---

Of course, the better implementation still would be to avoid assignment and just:

```cpp
constexpr std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    return 1;
}

static_assert(index_for_type().has_value());
```

Or, in the original function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::optional<size_t> index_for_type() noexcept
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return 1;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}
```

This works just fine, even in C++17.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. One overload of `operator=` I didn't notice was not `constexpr`, and I ended up calling that one, of course.

Comment: And I agree that returning the proper value without unnecessary assignment is much cleaner in this case, except this is a simplified example of a larger piece of code where it's not at all that simple to remove the need for assignment.